# Invoke a specific Window via shortcut in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, webcam

I want to invoke the " **Webcam Settings Window** " directly, without the need of any program.

For now, i do that by opening Skype > Options > Video Settings > Webcam Settings.

[image: Skype Webcam Settings]

Or Open Broadcaster Software Like so.

[image: OBS Webcam Settings]

For example, if i want to invoke the (**Folder Options Window**) from desktop i use this shortcut line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Options_RunDLL
```

It seems like any program can open the Webcam Settings Window, But not directly.

Any Solution ?

> *Note : My Webcam uses the system-supplied (USB) Video Class driver 1.1*

Comment: I do not recognize this as a Windows dialog.  Do you know of a way to open this *without* first going through a 3rd-party program? That might provide a clue of how to independently open the dialog.

Comment: I can't think of another way.